# Show input fields based on selection jQuery/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm generating options in a select field from a database and the showing certain input fields based on the users selection.

```
foreach($options as $key => $value)
      {
          if ($current==$key){
              $html .= "<option selected='selected' value='$key' name='$value'>$value</option>";
          } else {
              $html .= "<option value='$key' name='$value'>$value</option>";
          }

      }
```

Here are the input fields using dynamic variables from the database:

```
<input style='display:none;' type='text' class='_{$status_id}' value='{$question}' name='answers[$status_id][$id]' onfocus=\"this.value = this.value=='{$question}'?'':this.value;\" onblur=\"this.value = this.value==''?'{$question}':this.value;\" />
```

Here is the current jQuery code for showing the specific input fields based on the users selection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rfq_select").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if (selected == '1'){
            $("._1").css("display", "block");
            $("._2").css("display", "none");
            $("._3").css("display", "none");
        } else if (selected == '2'){
            $("._1").css("display", "none");
            $("._2").css("display", "block");
            $("._3").css("display", "none");
        } else if (selected == '3'){
            $("._1").css("display", "none");
            $("._2").css("display", "none");
            $("._3").css("display", "block");
        } else if (selected == '4'){
            $("._1").css("display", "none");
            $("._2").css("display", "none");
            $("._3").css("display", "none");
        } 
        else {
            $("._1").css("display", "none");
            $("._2").css("display", "none");
            $("._3").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm wondering how I can change the jQuery code to be more dynamic. If I were to add a new option in the database, say option "4", i wouldn't want to come to the page and add the "._4" to each of those options every time a new option is added to the database.

Updated the jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit_table input[type=text]").hide();
    $(".rfq_select").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("." + selected).show();
        $("#edit_table input[type=text]").not("." + selected).hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("._" + selected)` for dynamically selecting the correct input.

```
$(".rfq_select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('input[type=text]').hide();// hide all inputs
    $("._" + selected).show();// show the selected input 
});
```

Comment: won't it hide all other input elements with type text that are present on the page even if they don't have class with _val pattern?

Comment: @rakeshjain - yes it would. But for a more specific selector we need markup from OP which isn't available.

Comment: won't this $('input[class^=_]') be a safer choice?

Comment: @rakeshjain - may be but what if OP has a radio button somewhere in the page with class `_radio`? That would get hidden. We really need OP's markup to be exact.

Comment: What extra markup would be helpful? I tried using this:
    $(".rfq_select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('input[type=text]').hide();// hide all inputs
    $("._" + selected).show();// show the selected input 
});

But didn't work.

Comment: @user2033433 - what happens when you write `console.log(selected)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rfq_select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('input[class^=_]').hide();// hide all inputs
    $("._" + selected).show();// show the selected input 
});
```